# du shows large space but inside directory it doesn't show the space

Tags: linux, disk-space, du

I've been trying to track down used space with du, and I'm seeing some odd behavior.

```
[root@server01 /]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2       32G   32G  190M 100% /
devtmpfs        894M     0  894M   0% /dev
tmpfs           919M   12K  919M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           919M   17M  903M   2% /run
tmpfs           919M     0  919M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           184M     0  184M   0% /run/user/69023
tmpfs           184M     0  184M   0% /run/user/0

[root@server01 /]# du -sh * | sort -h | tail -3
1.2G    opt
1.4G    usr
28G     home

[root@server01 home]# du -sh * | sort -h | tail -3
80K     user1
168M    user2
28G     user3

[root@server01 user3]# du -sh * | sort -h | tail -3
480K    trash
1.5M    redis-stable.tar.gz
58M     redis-stable
```

As you can see, I tracked it all the way down to /home/user3, but inside /home/user3 there aren't any large files.

It's NOT open files, I've rebooted the server to clean up any lingering processes that might be holding open files.  It's not something hidden under a mount (it's all a single filesystem).

What other options could this be?

Comment: Try this (finding files 100MB or larger): `find /home -type f -size +100M`.

Comment: That did it.  It was buried in a dot directory that du didn't pick up.  Thanks!